# Mysql insert column with function

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-function

I want to add column if the column exist on table. But i my code doesn't work i get error the error message is ;

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'ColumnType DEFAULT (     CASE DefaultValue   WHEN NULL THEN
>         SELECT          'NULL' ' at line 11

**My Code MySql code block**

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER FUNCTION `AddTableColumn` (
    TableName VARCHAR (500),
    ColumnName VARCHAR (500),
    IsPrimary TINYINT (4),
    IsNull TINYINT (4),
    DefaultValue VARCHAR (500),
    ColumnType VARCHAR (500)
) RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE TableName ADD COLUMN
IF NOT EXISTS ColumnName ColumnType DEFAULT (
    CASE DefaultValue
    WHEN NULL THEN
        SELECT
            'NULL'
        ELSE
            SELECT
                DefaultValue
            END
)(
    CASE IsNull
    WHEN 1 THEN
        (SELECT 'IS NULL')
    ELSE
        SELECT
            ('IS NOT NULL')
        END
)(
    CASE IsPrimary
    WHEN 1 THEN
        (SELECT 'PRIMARY KEY')
    ELSE
        SELECT
            ''
        END
) RETURN 0;


END;

;
```

Comment: Please don't tag database engines randomly! If you are not using SQL Server, don't mention it.

Comment: What ? I don't understand you ?  Its a question about t-sql Syntax !

Comment: MySQL uses T-SQL? News to me.. All my life I've laboured under the misapprehension that T-SQL -> SQLServer. So.. I'm not sure which db you're actually using, but you appear to be trying to store column names as strings in a call to ALTER TABLE, and I don't know of a DB engine that supports this. Essentially, you're calling `ALTER TABLE 'mytab' ADD COLUMN 'mycol' 'varchar(500)'`.. The actual command you'd execute in a query tool would be `ALTER TABLE mytab ADD COLUMN mycol varchar(500)`. You should be looking for something more like `EXEC 'ALTER TABLE ' + mytabname + ' ADD COLUMN ' + mycol` ...

Comment: @Zarzamora "*Transact-SQL (T-SQL) is Microsoft's and Sybase's proprietary extension to the SQL (Structured Query Language) used to interact with relational databases.*" ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL)). Your error message actually says MariaDB, which is a MySQL fork.

Comment: Okay thank you for your information